# %userprofile% on .bat is not working

Tags: batch-file

My script in `.bat` is as follows:

```
@echo off
mode 34,18
color f0
start /min "" "%userprofile%\Arquivos Extratos"&start CieloTan.iim"
echo.
echo.
echo Extraindo os Extratos...
echo Aguarde...
echo.
echo.
timeout /nobreak /t 300 >nul 2>nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Ajustando Arquivo de texto...
echo Aguarde...
echo.
echo.
ren "%userprofile%\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\extract.csv" "extract.txt" >nul 2>nul
move "%userprofile%\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\extract.txt" "%userprofile%\Arquivos Extratos\extract.txt" >nul 2>nul
set "$file=extract.txt"
set "$search=Previsto"
set $repl[2]=TOTAL         
set $repl[3]=Visa            
set $repl[4]=Mastercard  
set $repl[5]=Amex          
set $repl[6]=Sorocred     
set $repl[7]=Elo              
set $repl[8]=Diners         
set $repl[9]=Agiplan       
set $repl[10]=Banescard   
set $repl[11]=Cabal          
set $repl[12]=Credsystem 
set $repl[13]=Hipercard   
set $repl[14]=Credz         
set $repl[15]=Hiper          
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $count=1
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%$file%) do (
   call:replace "%%a" !$count!
   set/a $count+=1
   )
)> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"
echo. >> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"
echo ---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN --- >> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"
del extract.txt
mkdir "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
move "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt" "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
exit/b
:replace
set "$line=%~1"
set $repl=!$repl[%2]!
set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
echo !$line!
if "%2"=="1" echo.
if "%2"=="2" echo.
```

But there is an error in the following part of the code:

```
mkdir "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
move "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt" "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
```

When the script runs, it is creating a folder called "Desktop\Extratos Bancos" in "C:\Users". It isn't recognizing my current username. Can someone help me?

---

See the image below, where it creating the directoy:

[image: Directory tree]

Comment: Maybe it's the blank spaces on the name of dirs... no? DOS does not like blank spaces...

Comment: Is username parameter specified on the command line as a parameter? In that case you need to use a different method to specify the proper argument, see here: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html  That same web page discusses environment vars also in case you meant to use those.

Comment: @statosdotcom DOS doesn't support spaces in names. But windows does

Comment: @statosdotcom - the code in the question isn't valid DOS batch (the old `for` loops didn't have a `/f` flag), so this is clearly Windows NT batch, which is fine with spaces in paths when they're surrounded by quotes, which these are.

Comment: If you enter `Set` at the command prompt, you should get a listing of your current environment variables with their values. If `UserName` is not part of that output, then you should fix your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your title, it's `username`, not `userprofile` that appears to be the source of the problem.

Normally, the OS sets both of these variables (amongst others) and it is seen as poor programming practice to vary their contents.

I suspect that a previous batch has been run which has altered `username` - it's an attractive and meaningful variablename for inexperienced batchers to use.

Another indication of inexperience is the absence of a `setlocal` command directly after the `@echo off`. Whereas this is not *compulsory*, it ensures that changes made to the environment by the batch are discarded when the batch ends so they do not accumulate with successive batch runs.

Hence I'd check that `username` is non-empty on starting this batch, so perhaps add

```
echo username=%username%
if not defined username echo no username&pause&goto :eof
```

after the `@echo off` to warn and abort.

Elsewhere in the script, `userprofile` is used. I can't see any reason for the change in the lines in question to `c:\users\%username%` as this would *normally* be the same as `%userprofile%`.

---

After posting of relevant detail:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "user_name=!M D!"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
DIR /ad "%destdir%"
ECHO ---------------------------------
MD "%destdir%\%user_name%\Banquo's ghost"
DIR /ad "%destdir%"
ECHO ---------------------------------
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
MD "%destdir%\%user_name%\Banquo's ghost"
DIR /ad "%destdir%"
ECHO ---------------------------------

GOTO :EOF
```

The issue is that your username is `!M D!` and you have invoked `delayedexpansion` so batch substitutes the value of variable `username` (I used `user_name` as I don't like changing system-set variables) hence `...!M D!...` and then substitutes the value of `M D` which is *empty*.

The above demonstration duplicates your situation, reports the current attempt to create the directory, then a cure - to turn `delayedexpansion` off.

Comment: It didn't work...there's another way to the bat create the directory "Extratos Banco" in my desktop? using %username% or %userprofile% isn't working...

Comment: Sadly, "isn't working" doesn't explain much. Is the `mkdir` being executed? What does `mkdir` return ? Is there an error message created? What do the variables `username` and `userprofile` contain at the time that the `mkdir` is executed?

Comment: It's making a directory "Desktop\Extratos Bancos" in the 'C:\Users' folder. (C:\Users\Desktop\Extratos Bancos) 
It doesn't entering on my current user and creating the directory on my desktop. (C:\Users\xxxuserxxx\Desktop\Extratos Bancos)

I put a pic on my question showing what's happening.

Comment: @William: tellus the exact output of `echo "%username%,%userprofile%"`

Comment: Its worked fine! Good! But i want use it on another computers, with different users name...There's a way for it recognize automatically the user? and also make the direcotory on the desktop of that user? Thanks

Comment: It will do that automatically as the username is assigned to the variables `username` and `userprofile` automatically. It's only the presence of `!` which becomes a special character in `delayedexpansion` mode that caused your problem in the first place.